# How to get the IPV4 address for an interface from /proc

Tags: linux, ip, proc

Is there a clean, simple way to get an IP address for a network interface from `/proc`, similar to the way I can get the MAC address for a network interface?
Ideally I would just type cat `/proc/<foo>/{interface_name}` and get the IPv4 address.

I'd rather not run anything other than `cat`.

Answer (score 63):

Under the `/proc` directory, you can also find the IPv4 addresses in the Forwarding Information Base table, at `/proc/net/fib_trie`

The table is pretty intelligible doing a mere `cat`, first comes the `Main:` and then `Local:`

```
cat /proc/net/fib_trie
```

or to see your network, IP addresses and netmask:

```
cat /proc/net/fib_trie | grep "|--"   | egrep -v "0.0.0.0| 127."
       |-- 193.136.1.0
       |-- 193.136.1.2
    |-- 193.136.1.255
       |-- 193.136.1.0
       |-- 193.136.1.2
    |-- 193.136.1.255
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the interface for each IP address?

Comment: They appear in a pre-determined order; probably priority, but that can be changed; other than that, no.

Comment: `/proc/net/fib_trie` isn't available on my RHEL 6.6 system here at work

Comment: @villapx fib_trie is not present on 2.6 kernels.

Comment: There's no way to associate ip addresses with interface in fib_trie.

Comment: @ZioByte There is a pre-defined order, but from the table alone, having several interfaces, not really. Now, if you only have one like eth0....

Comment: Then it's not a valid answer. My understanding of question (and what I'm looking for) is: Is there a way to get from /proc (or /sys, i.e.: without spawning three processses) the equivalent of: `ip a show dev <device> | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'`?

Comment: @ZioByte That is the best you can come up with using /proc alone afaik. There is some order to it, kind of eth0/eth1 and so on, but you will never know when an interface has several IP addresses.

Comment: Any further "enhancement" is possible if we allow also /sys usage? *Background*: I'm polling in a (reasonably) tight loop to see if/when a certain device gets it's IP address, so I would like to keep overhead to a minimum.

Comment: @ZioByte i am always curious for that kind of stuff, unfortunately I within a few hours of entering a plane for another continent and just popping by here with access to a Linux machine the next month. I am used to abuse SNMP for this kind of stuff actually. (for monitoring purposes)

Answer (score 7):

```
$ awk '/32 host/ { print f } {f=$2}' <<< "$(</proc/net/fib_trie)"
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Why `<<< "$(</proc/net/fib_trie)"` instead of a simple `</proc/net/fib_trie`?

Comment: @fra-san: `awk '/32 host/ { print f } {f=$2}' /proc/net/fib_trie` works the same

Comment: there is no ip command many of official docker containers, then your answer solved my problem. `awk '/32 host/ { print f } {f=$2}' /proc/net/fib_trie | sort | uniq | grep -v 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @God could you pl explain the `awk` syntax? The `/32 host/` would match lines containing that `32 host`. For me, these are lines like `32 host LOCAL`. `$2` would return the 2nd field from the line... so, what does `print f` do? ... and what would be its value? Why does `f=$2` come after `print 2`. (I thought I knew `awk` enough.)

Comment: @Harry It basically does this: For every line it saves $2 in f. But if the line contains "32 host" then print `f` that was saved from the previous line. After printing f, save $2 again

Comment: @fra-san I can never be sure, of course, but this answer looks a lot like [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082822/2521769), which uses the same idiosyncratic syntax.

Answer (score 6):

It might be possible to associate network addresses from `/proc/net/fib_trie` with interfaces from `/proc/net/route`:

```
  $ awk '/^[^I]/ {print $1 " " $2}' /proc/net/route
  br0 0001020A
  br0 FE01020A
```

..and to convert the hexadecimal network addresses with:

```
$ echo FE01020A | xxd -r -p | hexdump -e '/1 "%u."' | tac -s'.' | sed 's/\.$//'
10.2.1.254
```

Answer (score 1):

I just posted this similar answer on the Ubuntu community:

If you're lucky (and hostnames are set up properly), `hostname -i` will provide the local IP address. If not, or if you have multiple IP addresses, it will probably return the localhost address `127.0.0.1`. The command `hostname -I` will report all machine-local IP (v4 and v6) addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $'g/32 host LOCAL/-1s/\s*|-- //p\n Q'|ed -s /proc/net/fib_trie`

```
10.0.0.20
127.0.0.1
192.168.122.1
```