# Getting the IP address of a given interface

Tags: awk, pipe, ip, ifconfig

I need the IP (v4) address of a device I specify. The response will be later used in a script. This is what I have:

```
$ IFACE=eth1
$ ifconfig $IFACE |grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
10.0.0.33
```

Is there a cleaner (shorter) way of doing this?

EDIT: **ifdata** is exactly what I need. Solution found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84263/126008

Comment: If in Linux, you should be using `ip`

Comment: Note that one NIC may be assigned a very large number of IPs. I think they limit it to 250 or so now. Before you could have 65530 or so...

Answer (score 2):

It's neither cleaner, nor shorter really, but I think you should use `ip` instead of `ifconfig`. It's current, maintained, and perhaps more importantly for your purpose, it produces a consistent & parsable output.

If you want the IPv4 address for `eth0`:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | awk '{print $4}'
192.168.1.166/24
```

which is in CIDR notation. If CIDR notation isn't wanted it can be stripped:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d "/" -f 1 
192.168.1.166
```

Your question specified you wanted an address for an interface you specified. I think the answers above provide that, but if you want the IPv4 address for the host you're on, perhaps `hostname` is easier/more concise:

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $1}'
```

Or, if you want the IPv6 address:

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $2}'
```

Finally, one other option that IMHO is "most elegant" gets the IPv4 address for whatever interface is used to connect to the specified remote host (8.8.8.8 in this case). Courtesy of @gatoatigrado in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474172/how-to-find-network-interface-name):

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{ print $NF; exit }'
192.168.1.166
```

As a script:

```
$ RHOST=8.8.8.8  
$ ip route get $RHOST | awk '{ print $NF; exit }'
```

Which could be useful on a host with multiple interfaces and route specifications.

Comment: I was working on my answer when this question was marked as a duplicate. I'll leave it here, but have also posted it to the question [**"How to get my own IP address and save it to a variable in a shell script?"**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-and-save-it-to-a-variable-in-a-shell-script) designated as the original (?) by the admins here.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!