# Is there a "hostname -I" alternative that works on most Unix-like systems?

Tags: bash, ip, command

I am writing a Bash script that requires the internal/private IP address. On a Linux system I normally use the `hostname -I` command. However, this does not work on some other Unix-like systems, most notably MacOS.
Is there any command that does return the private IP address, that is present on most (if not all) Unix-like systems?

Comment: Some of my systems have two (or even more) internal private IP addresses. Which one of these equal-weight addresses should be returned?

Comment: @roaima, on my system, `hostname -I` returns all of them, though only the IPv4 ones (at least not the link-local IPv6 ones), and it seems to exclude the address of the loopback interface.

Comment: I do not know how up to date this information is: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line

Comment: @roaima, looking at the code, it loops over network interfaces, skips the loopback interface, interfaces that are not up, link-local IPv6 ones,

Comment: See also: [How to get my own IP address and save it to a variable in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48315) (the perl approach should be fairly portable, and may give you a more useful result than `hostname -I` depending on what exactly you want to do)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This fits my needs perfectly. Thank you very much.