# How can I store all the lines emitted by while loop in a single varianle in shell?

Tags: shell, text-processing, variable

As far as I know, while loops in shell are executed in a sub-shell, so they cannot modify variables outside the loop.

I'm writing a shell script and I want to store all the internal IPs of my machine into a single variable and so process this variable with a for loop to filter them one by one with iptables.

I could write this piece of code:

```
ip route show default | awk '{ print $5 }' | while read line; do
  ip address show dev ${line} scope global | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | while read line; do
    echo "${line} "
  done
done
```

Output:

```
10.17.0.49 
192.168.1.4
```

My question is:

How can I store all these lines emitted by a while loop into a single variable (as while loop variables are volatile)?

Comment: It's almost never necessary to store data in intermediate variables. Are you not wanting to use the IP addresses fro further processing? If so, then why not do that processing in your loop?  Also, what do you mean by "volatile"? You mean "local to the subshell"?

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I want to use the IP addresses for further processing. I think I will have to processes in a loop then. Volatile, I mean "local to the subshell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways of doing that (**in bash**):

1. Using `< <(command)` called process substitution (this does not pass the content through a pipe to the `while` loop ).
2. Using `{ code or commands }` called command grouping.

So if you want to store all IP in a variable (or array in this case) you can use this code:

**Process substitution:**

```bash
process_subs () {
   local array=()
   while read -r line; do
     while read -r line; do
       array+=("$line")
     done < <(ip address show dev "${line}" scope global | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}')
   done < <(ip route show default | awk '{ print $5 }')

   echo Array: "${array[@]}"
   echo Length: ${#array[@]}
}
```

**Command grouping:**

```bash
command_grouping () {

ip route show default | awk '{ print $5 }' |  while read -r line; do
ip address show dev "${line}" scope global | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | { 
         local array=()
            while read -r line; do
            array+=("$line")
         done

      echo Array: "${array[@]}"
      echo Length: ${#array[@]}
      }
      done 
}
```

Comment: First solution looks in line with what I would suggest myself. Perhaps I'm missing something though because I don't see how your "command grouping" solution addresses the issue. The input to `while read` still comes via pipe, thus any variable setup will live and die within the loop.

Comment: @bxm yeah, the command grouping doesn't really resolve the problem of the variables inside a while but it's a possible solution to make use of them. The downside of that method is that you have to define all your code that depends on the variables inside the command grouping.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the advice! I will update the code

Answer (score 3):

To print all the global scope local addresses of the interfaces involved in default routes, I'd use the JSON format which can be processed programmatically in a more reliable way:

```bash
perl -MJSON -le '
  $default_routes = decode_json(qx(ip -j route show default));
  for (@$default_routes) {$devs{$_->{dev}} = 1}
  $addresses = decode_json(qx(ip -j address show));
  for (@$addresses) {
    if ($devs{$_->{ifname}}) {
      for (@{$_->{addr_info}}) {
        print $_->{local} if $_->{scope} eq "global";
      }
    }
  }'
```

Or the same using `jq`:

```bash
ip -j address show |
  jq -r --argjson devs "$(
      ip -j route show default|jq 'map({"key":.dev})|from_entries'
    )" '.[]|select(.ifname|in($devs)).addr_info[]|
      select(.scope == "global").local'
```

(it needs a relatively recent version of `iproute2` though for JSON output support).

To get it (or more generally every line of the output of some command) into a `bash` array, use:

```bash
readarray -t array < <(
  that-command above
)
```

If the aim is to get the source IP address that packets going out on the default route would get, see for instance [my answer](/a/48315) to [How to get my own IP address and save it to a variable in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8518).

Answer (score 2):

To answer succinctly the actual question posed irrespective of context of how to store the output of a while loop:

To store the output into a file, e. g. `/path/to/file`:

```
while command; do
    thing
done > /path/to/file
```

To store the output into a variable, e. g. `my_var`:

```
my_var="$(while command; do thing; done)"
```